# React Native run native push didn't work

Tags: react-native

I'm using a custom Navigator written in native code.

I'm trying to run it as `[self.navigationController pushViewController]`, but it doesn't work.

The method executes but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Or give [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) a good read